# Can I publish something in my wall of facebook?

Tags: 7, social-network

I need to publish something in the user's facebook wall, when you entered the site, automatically.

This is the code that I actually use.

```
function publish(){
    global $user;
    $attachment = array(
            'name' => 'Name app',
            'href' => url('http://....', array('absolute' => TRUE)),
            'description' => 'Use this application.',
          );

    $user_message = t('Check out the latest application on !site...', array('!site' => t('My Drupal for Facebook powered site')));

    $actions = array();

    $actions[] = array('text' => t('Read More'),
                       'href' => url('http://....', array('absolute' => TRUE)),
                      );

    fb_stream_publish_dialog(array('user_message' => $user_message,
                                  'attachment' => $attachment,
                                   'action_links' => $actions,
                            ));
}
```

This code work, but it publish again the text when I edit the page, or I go to a different page.

Is there a module (for publish), or another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a session variable, or a cookie, when sent the first time; check that always.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a module to publish nodes on Facebook, there is the [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) module.

> This set of modules and themes turns Drupal into a platform for developing Facebook Applications. This allows you to embed your content and features within facebook, or allow facebook users onto your site via Facebook Connect.
>
> With Drupal for Facebook, you can harness all the power of Drupal in you Facebook App. **If you already have content in Drupal, you can expose it on Facebook.**

Read [the online documentation for the Drupal for Facebook module](http://drupal.org/node/195035) to understand which libraries are required, and need to be installed; enable the Facebook API, and the FB Streams modules.